# grep command running in if statement

Tags: bash, unix

```
if ! grep $1 'dict'; then
firstword=$1
firstletter=${firstword:0:1};
echo $firstletter

else
    echo "hello"
fi
```

I'm not sure if it's grep that's running, but when the case is that the word `Now` is in the file `dict` it prints the word `Now` to the standard output. If I put in `Noww` and `Noww` isn't in it, it will just print out `N`. What's causing it to print out `Now`?

Answer (score 1):

> What's causing it to print out "Now"?

`grep` is printing out `Now`, because that's what `grep` does by default: it prints out input lines which match the pattern.

If you don't want `grep` to do that, use the `-q` option. Then it will only set the return status, which is what `if` cares about.

(from `man grep` on a Linux system):

```
 -q, --quiet, --silent
      Quiet;  do not write anything to standard output.  Exit
      immediately with zero status if any match is found, even
      if an error was detected...
```

Comment: Ah thanks, for some reason I did not see that in the options.

Comment: If this answer fulfilled your needs. You should appreciate the help using Accepting the Answer rather saying Thanks in Comment. :)